# SQL Command not filling data reader

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am working on a nested repeater.  My issue seems to be at the moment, that when I execute my SQL command that no data is returned to the data reader.  Even when I run the exact same query (Copy and Pasted) into SQL Server.

My noteDrClient reader does not contain data, it does however know that there are 5 columns in the table.  I have no idea what to do at this point or why no data is being passed into the data reader.  Can anyone see an obvious problem?

```
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=*;User   ID=*;Password=*;Integrated Security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;");
```

Above is my connection string. Please notice that I have Multiple Active Result Sets set to true.  I did this because I kept getting errors about my data reader being open, even though it was closed.

```
   protected void rptList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
        if ((item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) ||
            (item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
        {

            System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord rd = (System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord)e.Item.DataItem;

            Repeater nestedRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("NotesRepeater") as Repeater;
            string FID = rd[0].ToString();


            using (cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE FID = 1356;", con)) ;

            SqlDataReader noteDrClient = cmd2.ExecuteReader();  //no data is being filled to the data reader... even though this command pulls data in SQL Server Management Studio.

            if (noteDrClient.Read()) {   //bind the repeater if there is data to bind
                    nestedRepeater.DataSource = noteDrClient;
                    nestedRepeater.DataBind();
            }

            noteDrClient.Close();                                   




        }
```

Comment: Are you logged in with the same user in Management Studio than the user configured in the connection string?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using statement is disposing the SqlCommand before you have a chance to use it.  Additionally, you're attempting to bind to a DataReader.  Get the results from the data reader into a collection of "Note" entities and bind to the collection instead.

```
        using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE FID = 1356;", con))
        {

            using(SqlDataReader noteDrClient = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
            {

                while (noteDrClient.Read()) 
                {   
                    Note n = new Note();
                    ... get note from data reader
                    notes.Add(n); // add note to collection
                }
            }
        } 

        // bind child
        nestedRepeater.DataSource = notes;       
        nestedRepeater.DataBind();
```

***Edit:***

You might want to look into the DataAdapter - http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/57/Displaying-One-To-Many-Relationships-with-Nested-Repeaters

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating an additional connection string instead of reusing the same connection string I had been using for primary repeater.  The Data is still not binding, but it does exist.

```
            using (cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE FID = 1356;", con2)) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the semicolon in your query may cause problems.

Try using quotation marks around the value like this:

`SELECT * FROM notes WHERE FID = '1356;'`

If the semicolon is not part of the value:

`SELECT * FROM notes WHERE FID = '1356'`

Comment: A semi-colon denotes the end of a SQL statement.  If the data type for FID is an INT, the quotation marks are unnecessary, but the semi-colon is valid.